# Setting Sqlite ThreadingMode when using sqlite-net + async

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net

I'm trying to set Sqlite ThreadMode to Serialized in my Xamarin.iOS project. Using classic Sqlite, one finds this method on the connection class:

> SqliteConnection.SetConfig(SQLiteConfig.Serialized);

However I'm using [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) (+async) and can't find a way to set this configuration property.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I had to update SQLite-Net (and SQLite-Net-PCL etc) to 2.5.

Then this option can be accessed through the platform specific implementation:

```
public Repository(IPlatform platform)
    {
        _platform = platform;
        _platform.SqlitePlatform.SQLiteApi.Config(ConfigOption.Serialized);

        _db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(() =>
            new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnectionWithLock(
            _platform.SqlitePlatform,
            new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnectionString(_platform.DatabasePath, true)));
    }
```

Comment: Does this constructor still exist? I can't find it in the github repository linked and neither can I find it in my code. What namespaces do I need? What is the `IPlatform` interface?

Comment: there is no  such constructor

Comment: https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net.Async/SQLiteAsyncConnection.cs#L48